# Chromecast Android Games GLES2?

Tags: android, opengl-es, chromecast, google-cast-sdk

Does the Cast SDK support rendering 3D objects natively?  Like can I upload content for the Chromecast device to render internally on its own hardware?  The Chromecast hardware does support GLES2 natively.

Or can I stream GLES2 rendered content to the device?  Does the SDK have tools for Video Game streaming in general?

Does the Chromecast hardware accelerate HTML5 canvas objects?